# Unable to print words in reverse order

Tags: c, pointers

I have to print some words in reverse order using pointers.

For example, given "Hello World", output should be "World Hello".

This is what I have done so far, but it doesn't print anything:

```
void swap(char *ar){

    int tmp1[10], tmp2[10], j = 0, k = 0, a, b, z,i; // must use pointers

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(ar[i] == ' ')  //if there's a space, store the characters before the space to another array and after the space to another
        {
            for(j = 0; j<i; j++) // tmp1
                tmp1[j] = ar[j];

            for( j = 0; j<MAX-i; j++) //MAX - i would be range of j
                for(k = i+1; k<MAX; k++) //tmp2
                    tmp2[j] = ar[k];
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        while(tmp2[i] != '\0' && i<sizeof(tmp2))  // finding the size of tmp2
            a++;
    }
    for(j=0; j<a; j++) // overwriting the original array
        ar[j] = tmp2[j];
    j++; // incrementing j so that there would be a space between the new array
    z = j; 
    i=0;

    while(1) //finding the size of tmp1
    {
        while(tmp1[i] != '\0' && i<sizeof(tmp1))
            b++;
    }
    //idk pls help
    for( z=0 ; z<MAX; z++) //overwriting the original array
        for(k = 0; k<b; k++)
            ar[z] = tmp1[k];
        //idk pls help

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) // outputting the required result
        printf("%c", *(ar+i));
    printf("\n");
}//eg if input is Hello World   the output should be World Hello//idk pls help
```

The main function calls the function as `swap(word1)` where `word1` is `char word1[] = {'h','e', etc)`

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I guess your problem is the `while (1)` loop... "Infinite loop".

Comment: It's not printing anything

Comment: Please edit the question and indent your code.

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back you last change though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `while (1)` loop...

Infinite loop...

I hope this can help.

Comment: hmmm so what should i do instead?

Comment: I tell what can be your problem... As you are learning, you have to study a bit more and try another solutions, by yourself. If I say what to do, you will not learn well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use strtok to split the string and print the 2nd word before the first? What you are doing now is very unefficient , 6 loops and 10 syscalls, you can do 1 loop and 1 syscall! If you want I can write the code for you, just let me know!

```
    void swap(char *ar){
    int i, z;
    for(z = 0; ar[z]; z++) //find the index of the space
      {
        if (ar[z] = ' ')
          break;
      }
    for(i = z + 1; ar[i]; i++)
        printf("%c",ar[i]); //print from space to end of string
    printf(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < z; i++)
        printf("%c",ar[i]); //print from start of string to space
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to store in another array as well? Why not print right away? Also dont use MAX for loop condition , use ar[i] != Null instead to stop the loop

Comment: we dont need to store it in another array... hmm could you write it for me? srry

Comment: try this code should work! not the most efficient but for sure more straighforward!

Comment: The line "if (ar[z] = '  ') " should be " if (ar[z] = ='  ')